# CSS for numbers inside of circles, position is off for iOS

Tags: ios, css, position

I'm trying to style numbers inside of circles but it doesn't look the same in Chrome as it does on iOS.

Preview on Chrome

[image]

Preview on iOS

[image]

**Notice the numbers are not vertically centered on iOS**.

Yes, I have tried adding `vertical-align: center;` but it won't do the trick.

Here is my CSS

```
.circle {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   width: 20px;
   height: 10px;
   padding: 3px;
   background: #7DBCD8;
   border: 1px solid #599DBB;
   color: #FFF;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
   font-size: 10px;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px; 
}
```

with the HTML

```
<span class="circle">5</span>
<span class="circle">15</span>
<span class="circle">125</span>
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu9cT/7/).  How can I get this to look the same for iOS?

I have also tried a variety of other fonts which are native to iOS, but still the problem persists.

Comment: They're a bit off on Chrome on my PC to begin with (Win7, latest Chrome): http://d.pr/i/Vebv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`center` isn't a valid value for the `vertical-align` property. Equally, this issue doesn't appear to be iOS-specific as I too am having this problem on Chrome on Windows 7, your site is probably cached.

One way to fix the issue (your font appears to be too large to fit in the small container) is to simply increase the height of the span to 12px: [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Mu9cT/8/).

Another way is to replace `height:12px` with `line-height:10px`. [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Mu9cT/12/).

Both methods will increase the height of your spans, and I'm not sure if that's an undesirable effect in your case.

Comment: Using the following did the trick: `font: 10px/11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`  Similar but it seems to look a little better.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `line-height: 1em`.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical centering is and has allways been a huge pain. I like to use table-cells, they appear to be a fair cross-browser solution to the problem. Then again I'm just a noob myself.

What I would do is:

```
/* Not even touching this */
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #7DBCD8;
  border: 1px solid #599DBB;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
  font: 10px Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

/* to make your sub-span in to a table */
.circle > span {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

/* to make your sub-sub-span in to a table cell */
.circle > span > span {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And

```
<span class="circle">
  <span>
    <span>
      5
    </span>
  </span>
</span>

<span class="circle">
  <span>
    <span>
      5
    </span>
  </span>
</span>

<span class="circle">
  <span>
    <span>
      5
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

This will acutally vertically align your numbers, if that IS indeed your problem...